# viewDidLoad not Called for UIViewController with UIScrollView and UIPageControl

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to add a page with a UIScrollView and UIPageControl to my app.  I am making the call to the new class from a UITableView as below.

```
MultiPageViewController *mpvc = [[MultiPageViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MultiPageViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
[[self navigationController]pushViewController:mpvc animated:YES];
```

The viewDidLoad function is never called, thus my UIScrollview and UIPageControl are never initialized.  When I go along further and call viewWillAppear these objects are both still nil.  Further the view never appears only a white screen.  Below is the code from initWithNibName and viewDidLoad.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    NSLog(@"initWithNibName returned self != null");
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"View did load called");
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Is [self navigationController] == nil?

Comment: @rocky if is `nil` it won't do anything.

Comment: @rocky no it is not nil.  I had the following statement to check for that condition 
    'if (![self navigationController])
    {
        NSLog(@"navigationController is null");
    }'
to check for that condition and never saw the log statement.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard at all? Is initWithNibName:bundle: being called? Have you logged mpvc to see that it's not nil?

Comment: No this does not use storyboard.  The initWithNibName is being called and I can use the debugger to see the contents of mpvc and everything is there except my ScrollView and PageControl which are nil.